# Strange Config file error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am working on an application which requires AWS (Amazon Web Services) push notification services.

I am running this on a node server, when I run the curl http request I get this error:

```
Registering user with deviceId: nodeserver
{ [Error: Missing credentials in config]
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'SigningError',
  time: Tue Nov 17 2015 13:52:20 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  originalError: 
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     time: Tue Nov 17 2015 13:52:20 GMT+0000 (GMT),
     originalError: 
      { message: 'Connection timed out after 1000ms',
        code: 'TimeoutError',
        time: Tue Nov 17 2015 13:52:20 GMT+0000 (GMT) } } }
```

Does anybody know what this error is or if anybody has had this type of error before and knows how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Have you checked you have credentials in a config file accessible to AWS?

Comment: Hi Alex, I forgot to mention i am new to this haha! Where would i be able to find this?

Comment: http://www.adventuresofanentrepreneur.net/creating-a-mobile-appsgames-company/setting-up-aws-sns-to-send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices

Comment: This shows how to set it up for iOS, the example i am using is for Android, this does not show the credentials

Comment: It can be applied to either - it is about adding your RSA public key to your application and then using it for SNS... good luck!